# USBから起動するOSの解像度を変更したい

Tags: windows, ハードウェア, bios

**やりたいこと**
通常起動だと1920*1080で普通に使えますが、USBからOSを起動すると、解像度が800*600ぐらい
になってしまいます。その解像度を変更したいです。

**環境**
OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
システム製造元:Notebook
システム モデル: NK50SZ
BIOS バージョン:INSYDE Corp. 1.07.04TUN

**恐らく原因**
USBから起動させるために、最初にBIOSの画面に入ってUSBのOSを立ち上げているので、
BIOSの解像度がそのまま引き継がれているのではと考えています(BIOSの解像度と同じだと思うので)

**試したこと**
BIOSの画面を弄るぐらい。。
というのも、USB boot、BIOSの解像度について調べましたが、そもそもそれっぽい
情報が全然ないので、解決できませんでした。
知見がある方、教えていただきたいです！

Comment: おそらくBIOSは関係ないと思います。USBから起動後、デスクトップ画面を右クリックで画面解像度変更はできませんか？できたら、再起動で元に戻るか確認して見てください。

Comment: 追記、グラフィックボードのドライバーは入っていますか？

Comment: >デスクトップ画面を右クリックで画面解像度変更はできませんか？
「リモートデスクトップでは解像度が変更できません」のような感じで表示されていて制限がかかっているようで出来ません。
グラボも入っていますが、グラボの有無は関係あるのでしょうか。

Comment: "USB から起動する OS" についての情報をもう少し詳しく説明した方が回答のヒントになるかもしれません。Windows PE?

Comment: おそらく、グラフィックボードのドライバーが入っていないんだと思います。PCのメーカーのサイトでグラフィックボードのドライバーを探してインストールしてみてください。